# I want only the numbers between "LR" & "DT"

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

In cell `A1` I have `MPT LR 163 DT:19.04.2016`,
in `B1` I have `UFLED LR 7531596540 DT:19.04.2016`,  and in `C1` I have `Green LR 134534 DT:19.04.2016`.

I want only the numbers between "LR" & "DT".

For example: i want `163` from `A1`, `7531596540` from `B1`, and `134534` from B3

I want only one formula for all this. Is this possible? 
Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look in MID() and FIND()

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Show what you've attempted so far, and we'll (maybe) try to help fix that.

Comment: Are the numbers always the third part?

Answer (score 0):

let's suppose, that your cell is E6:

```
=MID(E6;FIND("LR";E6)+3;(FIND("DT";E6))-((FIND("LR";E6))+3))
```

Find what those funcions mean and you will understand. Next time you will do it alone.